# Angular 2 - Convenient way to store in session

Tags: angular

Is there a convenient way to save in sessionStorage without the need to manually watch for property changes and update?

I have a SearchComponent with a property "query" for example.

```
export class SearchComponent {
    private query: String;
    private searchResult: SearchResult;
    ...
```

Every time the query or the searchResult changes (and there are even more properties), i have to manually update sessionStorage.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('query', query);
```

Something like an annotation that does the job automatically would be great:

```
export class SearchComponent {
    @SessionStored
    private query: String;
    @SessionStored
    private searchResult: SearchResult;
    ...
```

I already found a similar solution [here](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localStorage). But this one did not work for *sessionStorage*.

Comment: `https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localStorage` works for `sessionStorage` too, according to the source code.

Comment: I read that too, but they had missing classes. Could just be an unstable build though...

Comment: angular2-localStorage looks like exactly what i need - but it does not work. "import {LocalStorage, SessionStorage} from "angular2-localstorage/WebStorage";" <- already fails as there is no file "WebStorage"

Comment: did you install it by `npm install --save angular2-localstorage`

Comment: Yes. I did like described in the readme.

Comment: yes you need unstable build. or only LocalStorage

Comment: but where and how do i get it from?

Comment: It works..I just checked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried & it is working perfectly fine for both LocalStorage & SessionStorage. Try using these steps:

Step 1:

```
npm install --save angular2-localstorage
```

Step 2:

```
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter'
import { SessionStorage } from 'angular2-localstorage/WebStorage'
constructor(storageService: LocalStorageService){}
```

Step 3:

```
@LocalStorage() public lastSearchQuery:Object = {}
```

or,

```
@SessionStorage() public lastSearchQuery:Object = {};
```

it is straight forward as mentioned in docs.

Reference: https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage