# Simulate a SESSION, with http request in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I have a situation in an angular app :

```
    this.http.get('myurl')
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data =>{
  this.data = data;
  // resolve(this.data);
  console.log('token', this.data);

});
```

This script, gets me the token I need to login, but from the API, it use to fetch the token in a session variable, with another url, that doesn't have any parameters, eg : http://myserver/myAPI/getUserData

How can I simulate a session with angular 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use localstorage to store the data returned from the service. or you can use a third party called ng2-cookies. Refer [this link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164758/angular-2-convenient-way-to-store-in-session)

Comment: I have to do another http.get, with another link, but no parameters for the token access, it needs the browsers session, is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.http.get('myurl')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data =>{
        this.data = data;
        // resolve(this.data);
       console.log('token', this.data);

        // this is my second URL, that needs to find an active session
         this.http.get('my2ndurl')
           .map(res => res.json())
           .subscribe(data =>{
             this.data = data;
            console.log('token', this.data);

        });

   });
```